# Split air conditioning unit with single cold unit but multiple output pipes

Tags: air-conditioning

I want to install AC in my house. I want a split unit, hot part outside, cold inside. The thing is I have a few small rooms and I'd rather not have to install multi-split system with a large cold unit in each room - I'd rather have a single cold unit with multiple outgoing cold pipes that I can run to each room. I can't find any such thing. Do they exist? Should I, for some reason, avoid installing such a system and perhaps manually converting conventional cold unit to multi-output cold unit?

What I want:

```
           cold pipe 1
                |
                |   +------ cold pipe 2
                |   |
+-----+       +------+
| Hot |=======| Cold |----- cold pipe n
+-----+       +------+
```

What I am finding

```
+-----+       +~^~^~^+
| Hot |=+==+==| Cold |
+-----+ || || +------+
        || ||
        || || +~^~^~^+
        || \==| Cold |
        ||    +------+
        ||
        ||    +~^~^~^+
        \=====| Cold |
              +------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are reaching for and not quite describing is a ducted indoor unit (or mini-ducted, using small high-velocity ducts.)

Those exist (they cost a good deal more at least when I was last shopping) and you take a considerable efficiency hit, because now instead of using a nice low-power fan that circulates air in a room with few restrictions, you're jamming air into ducts to blow it around, so the fan power consumption goes way up.

That puts one heat exchanger in a somewhat central location, and then distributes cooled or heated air. It's quite similar, though typically on a smaller scale, to a traditional old-fashioned furnace/AC system.

Tellingly, you draw only "cold pipes" from the indoor unit, with no return. Ducts (sort-of) work that way, with the air returning via the open space to an intake grille on the cold unit. If ducts are not what you mean, you may simply not understand that the "cold pipe" does not work without a heat exchanger, which is what's in the head units, and a return pipe for the warmed fluid/gas.

There are also inside head units that are specifically designed to be less obtrusive than "the usual" - they will still connect to the outside unit, with two pipes and some wires, as usual for any inside unit - but they are visually designed to look like something else, such as a somewhat chunky picture frame. Of course, they cost more than the basic unit, and may require using specific manufacturers, since not all manufacturers offer that sort of thing.

There are also indoor units that "look like" just a flat ceiling vent, but which extend up into the ceiling space and have one part of the vent taking air in, while the other blows conditioned air out. Again, with two pipes and wires back to the outdoor unit. In some cases they may look pretty much the same as the intake grille for one that has ducts blowing conditioned air elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you want a single outside unit (compressor) servicing 2 indoor units (air handlers)?

If this is correct then YES, such systems exist.  We have one in a our church, a heat pump system, that provided AC & heat for two rooms.  Each room's  temperature can be individually controlled.  But both rooms have to be in the same mode - cool or heat - or the system will lock itself out (no damage done).  This is because the common outside unit can only operate in cool or heat mode, not both simultaneously because there's only a single reversing valve.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not going to be very effective.  All the units I have seen have pipes to each internal unit.

The cheaper solutions have it so that all internal units are on cold or all are on hot.  The more expensive ones will give you individual control.

What you are looking for is a radiator like system.

> **Air to Water Heat Pumps**
> Air to water heat pump technology has re-invented the traditional radiator transforming it into a modern energy efficient heating option for both new and existing homes.

From [Heat Pump Powered Radiators](https://www.warmandcool.co.nz/heat-pump-radiators)

I am not associated with that site and I don't have any experience with them.  It's an example of what might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Mitsubihi makes a breakout box to minimize piping.  https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwiiwP3gnsj_AhWDNK0GHVanCFUYABAPGgJwdg&sig=AOD64_0ZFLSKY1niNInPRTIaY0ByAS8-mQ&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjo4Pbgnsj_AhVCHzQIHRliB2kQ9aACKAB6BAgDEC0&adurl=

I have seen mini-splits with ducts and they don't work all that well, a head unit in each room would give you much better performance.  I'm currently installing a two part (two outdoor units) in a large rental and one of them is up and running and they are awesome. I'd avoid ductwork if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of fluid to carry the heat, and it needs to be a loop.

You seem to be proposing using air as the fluid.  This requires really big ducts, or what's called a "duct-o-pus" by many. They're an aesthetic nightmare because they're huge, but the trade-off is it makes air conditioning easy. And that is why most American homes are built that way, with concealed ducts in walls and ceiling.  They are built with gas (sometimes electric) forced-air heaters with an air handler, and then it's easy to retrofit a common/cheap outdoor barrel air conditioner and evaporator unit in the air handler.  **If you already have forced-air heat, this is the only sensible way to do plain A/C**. Such a house can be A/C'd for under $3000.

But if you don't already have a ducted system, you're talking about adding an air handler and requisite ducting.

The other thing is, you keep drawing one-way flow but fluids aren't like that. You push air in, and it pushes other air out. If you don't provide a return path, you could be pushing it outside, and that means the system will be sucking hot wet air from outside to replace it. That's not very efficient.